# where can I find websites with good java source codes that work?

Tags: java

HI. I am a beginner/intermediate java programmer.I'd like to see codes of useful applications used in the real world. Could anyone tell me where to look for such source codes? thanks.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Super User. Programming questions are better suited to our cousin, Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 3):

SourceForge has numerous open source [projects which use Java](http://sourceforge.net/softwaremap/trove_list.php?form_cat=198) in some way. On the first page you'll see a lot of popular software you've probably used before.

Comment: Many thanks, John T. That looks like a great link. I'll spend some time checking that out! cheers

Comment: Just make sure you pick a project that has either good comments or basically written well - it can be a nightmare to read other peoples code when you are just learning... However, Source Forge is a great way to learn programming - find a project that deals with something you are interested in and take it apart until you can understand how it works!... +1

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend searching Google Code ( http://code.google.com/ ) for Java programs.

This last suggestion is a bit unorthodox, but have you considered competing at TopCoder.com?  After the first competition round you have the option to look at others' code.  The flip side is that you need to apply critical thinking - not everyone's solution will be correct, much less optimal!  You can't get any more real-world than that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

thank you Arkaaito.
I found the google code website very confusing to search. I didn't get many relevant searches for Java when I typed "java source code" into the search box. I'll continue trying.
As for competiting on Topcoder.com, I am not good enough in programming java to do that...perhaps you could suggest more links for me to study from to improve my skills?
I enjoy java labs that build on my programming fundamentals :-)

cheers.